# Leak information (new setting)

Tags: cryptanalysis, protocol-design, semantic-security, data-privacy, probabilistic-encryption

This question is similar to [Leak Information?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/59722/leak-information), but with new settings.

Let $a,b,c,d,e,f$ be selected at random from $\mathbb Z^*_q$. Also, let $r_1,r_2,r_3,z_1,z_2,z_3,p_1,p_2,p_3$ be selected at random from $\mathbb Z^*_q$.

is there a P.P.T adversary $A$ such that gets information about values a,b,c,d,e,f or Their relations, when the adversary $A$ has given the following information:

$$u_1=(r_1\cdot a,r_2\cdot b,r_3\cdot c,(r_1+r_2-r_3)\cdot d),$$

$$u_2=(z_1\cdot c,z_2\cdot d,z_3\cdot e,(z_1+z_2-z_3)\cdot f).$$

$$u_3=(p_1\cdot a,p_2\cdot b,p_3\cdot e,(p_1+p_2-p_3)\cdot f).$$

Comment: c is the only value in both u1 and u2. Anything similar to the last question won't be possible here. Maybe a completely different approach, don't know.

Comment: I changed the problem a little bit. i.e. I add random values $p_1,p_2,p_3$ and equation related to $u_3$.